# Is this common amongst many languages?

Tags: programming-languages, operators

In C++, the integer variable `bar` evaluates to 1 in this code

```
int foo = 0;
int bar = ++foo;
```

and 0 in this code

```
int foo = 0;
int bar = foo++;
```

Is this behavior prevalent in most popular languages?

Comment: Thats exactly to specification in languages with that operator. Have you looked at what those operators mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C-like languages, such as C++, Java, and C# all have this behavior.

The definitely not C-like languages such as ruby or python typically don't have an increment or decrement operator whatsoever.

So many popular languages do have this behavior, but other popular languages don't have those operators at all.

Comment: Python doesn't have `++`, but it does have `+=`.

Comment: @dan04, absolutely. I don't why you brought it up.

Comment: What about languages like Perl, which aren't C-like, but have `++` and `--`

Comment: @Jae, I believe Perl is like the C-like languages in this regard.

Comment: An interesting difference between Java and C/C++ is that result of more complex expressions *including* pre- and post-increment operators (such as `x = x++ + ++x - x--`) tend to be undefined/implementation-defined in C/C++ and are strictly defined in Java. That's a source of much "why doesn't this (insanely complex) code work in Java" questions. I don't know exactly, but I guess C# went the Java route on this one.